# Setup service account to authorize to Dialogflow

Tags: api, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I need to setup a service account to handle authentication to my dialogflow enterprise agent. I have had little luck in searching GCP documentation. Has anyone achieved this and do you have a decent tutorial? (Newbie)

Comment: You'll be looking for service account with DialogFlow API permissions. You can find service accounts under IAM & ADMIN section on google cloud console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check out following URLs for documentation on setting up a service account for dialogflow v2 agent. The minimum role permission you would require is `Dialogflow API -> Dialogflow API Client`

https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/quickstart
https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started